# MySQL Update - Set value in Table A with a value calculated from Table B

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two tables:

```
      TABLE_A                        TABLE_B
=================          =========================
ID  |  Value | Q           TABLE_A_VALUE | Q | Name
====|========|===          ==============|===|======
 2  |  999   | 1                999      | 1 | Cat
 3  |  777   | 1                888      | 2 | Cat
                                777      | 1 | Dog
                                666      | 2 | Dog
```

I need to carry out an update to change `TABLE_A.Q = 2 WHERE ID = 2` and in the same statement change `TABLE_A.VALUE` to the relevant `TABLE_B.TABLE_A_VALUE` performing a look-up to transform the `TABLE_A_VALUE` to the corresponding row with the same `Name` as the original value but the new `Q`

In other words, if I am updating the row in `TABLE_A` with`ID=2`, I want to:

1. Lookup the `Value` from `TABLE_A` in `TABLE_B` (999)
2. Find the corresponding `Name` in `TABLE_B` (Cat)
3. Find the corresponding `TABLE_A_VALUE` with the new `Q` (888)
4. Use this value in the `Update` statement

.

```
      TABLE_A                  TABLE_A        
=================        =================    
ID  |  Value | Q         ID  |  Value | Q     
====|========|===   =>   ====|========|===    
 2  |  999   | 1          2  |  888   | 2     
 3  |  777   | 1          3  |  777   | 1
```

This is the bit I am stuck on. I can:

`UPDATE TABLE_A SET Q=2 WHERE ID=2`

but I'm not sure about the lookup.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is the second `INNER JOIN` on `TABLE_B` to find rows with higher `Q`

```
UPDATE TABLE_A x
INNER JOIN TABLE_B y ON x.Value=y.TABLE_A_VALUE
INNER JOIN TABLE_B z ON y.Name=z.Name AND z.Q>y.Q
SET x.Q=z.Q, x.Value=z.TABLE_A_VALUE
WHERE x.ID=2
```